# Objective C : How to keep listening to incoming data on stdin?

Tags: objective-c, stdin, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to call a MacOS app written in Objective C from a Browser extension using [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/).

So far I have come up with this code which handles requests made with [chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/#native-messaging-client).

```objectivec
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSFileHandle *stdIn = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
    NSError * stdinError = nil;
    NSData * rawReqLen = [stdIn readDataUpToLength:4 error:&stdinError];
    if(rawReqLen == nil || stdinError != nil) return 1;
    NSUInteger reqLen;
    [rawReqLen getBytes:&reqLen length:4];

    NSData * req = [stdIn readDataUpToLength:reqLen error:&stdinError];
    if(stdinError != nil) return 1;

    handleRequest(req); // this does something depending on the received request

    return 0;
  }
}
```

This is working.

I need help figuring out how to use [chrome.connectNative](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/#native-messaging-client) to maintain the connection open. Specifically, my problem is to let the MacOS app keep listening to incoming messages until the port is closed by a call to port.disconnect from the browser extension.

I've tried this code which does not work.

```objectivec
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSFileHandle *stdIn = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                                          object:stdIn
                                                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                      usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSError * stdinError = nil;
      NSData * rawReqLen = [stdIn readDataUpToLength:4 error:&stdinError];
      if(rawReqLen == nil || stdinError != nil) exit(1);
      NSUInteger reqLen;
      [rawReqLen getBytes:&reqLen length:4];

      NSData * req = [stdIn readDataUpToLength:reqLen error:&stdinError];
      if(stdinError != nil) exit(1);

      handleRequest(req);
    }];
    [stdIn waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
  }
}
```

Does someone know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```objectivec
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSFileHandle *stdIn = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                                          object:stdIn
                                                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                      usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSError * stdinError = nil;
      NSData * rawReqLen = [stdIn readDataUpToLength:4 error:&stdinError];
      if(rawReqLen == nil || stdinError != nil) exit(1);
      uint32_t reqLen;
      [rawReqLen getBytes:&reqLen length:4];
      reqLen = OSSwapLittleToHostInt32(reqLen);

      NSData * req = [stdIn readDataUpToLength:reqLen error:&stdinError];
      if(stdinError != nil) exit(1);

      handleRequest(req);
      [stdIn waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
    }];
    [stdIn waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
  }

  NSRunLoop *loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
  [loop acceptInputForMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
  [loop run];
  return 0;
}
```

Calling `exit(1)` could also be replaced by a new call to `[stdIn waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];` if you want to keep the port opened instead.

This handles incoming requests well, but breaks the response: writing to stdout does not work anymore, I might need to stop the run loop for each response and restart it when done. (not tested yet)